# Looking for a simpler solution to a problem about the divisibility of combinatorial numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Here is the problem:

> For every positive integer r, there exists a natural number $n_r$ such that for every integer $n>n_r$, there is at least one $k$, where $1\leq k \leq n-1$,such that $C_n^k$can be divided by $p^r$, where $p$ is a prime.

My solution:

> let us firstly prove 2 lemmas.
>
> Lemma 1:Let $n,k$ be natural numbers, $p_i$ being the $i$th prime number. If for every integers $1\leq l \leq \sqrt[k]{n}$, we have $l|n$, then $n<p_{2k}^{k}$.
>
> proof:Suppose not, then we have $p_{2k}\leq \sqrt[k]{n}$, suppose $p_t^{\lambda_t}\leq \sqrt[k]{n} \leq p_t^{\lambda_t+1}$. Then we have 
>   $$
> p_1^{\lambda_1}p_1^{\lambda_2}...p_{2k}^{\lambda_{2k}}\ |\ n
> $$
>   so:
>   $$
> n\geq p_1^{\lambda_1}p_1^{\lambda_2}...p_{2k}^{\lambda_{2k}}
> $$
>   However, we have $p_1^{\lambda_1}p_2^{\lambda_2}> \sqrt[k]{n}$, $p_3^{\lambda_3}p_4^{\lambda_4}> \sqrt[k]{n}$  ... $p_{2k-1}^{\lambda_{2k-1}}p_{2k}^{\lambda_{2k}}> \sqrt[k]{n}$
>
> Hence we have :
>   $$
> n\geq p_1^{\lambda_1}p_1^{\lambda_2}...p_{2k}^{\lambda_{2k}}>(\sqrt[k]{n})^k = n
> $$ 
>   which is a contradiction.
>
> Lemma 2:If $n+1$ is not divided by $p$, $n>p^r$, then: $p^r | C_n^{n-p^r+1}$.
>
> Proof: We have:
>   $$
> (n+1)\times C_n^{n-p^r+1} = \frac{p^r \times (p^r +1)\times ... \times n \times (n+1)}{1\times 2 \times 3 \times  ... \times (n-p^r+1)}
> $$
>
> Since $(p^r +1)\times ... \times n \times (n+1) \equiv 1\times 2 \times 3 \times  ... \times (n-p^r+1)(mod p^r)$
>
> So $p^r|\frac{p^r \times (p^r +1)\times ... \times n \times (n+1)}{1\times 2 \times 3 \times  ... \times (n-p^r+1)}$, thus $p^r | (n+1)\times C_n^{n-p^r+1}$
>
> Since $(n+1)$ is not divided by $p$. Then $p^r| C_n^{n-p^r+1}$.
>
> Back to the problem:
>
> Set $n_r = p_{2r}^{r}-1$. Then for $n>n_r$, we have $n+1 > p_{2r}^{r}$. According to Lemma 1. we can see there is at least one prime which is smaller than $p_{2r}$ that cannot divide $n+1$. We denote the prime by $p$. According to lemma 2. we have $p^r | C_{n}^{n+1-p^r}$.

The solution looks fine to me. However, lemma 1 is not obvious, which I happen to hear about. Actually it was a problem I encountered. Fortunately, I found it an be applied here.

Besides the solution. I actually don't have valuable ideas, but I believe there is a simpler way to solve the problem. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

We have the identity$$ (n+1)\, \text{lcm}\left(\binom{n}{1}, \binom{n}{2}, \ldots, \binom{n}{n-1}\right) = \text{lcm}(1,2,\ldots, n+1).$$If $p$ is a prime number that does not divide $n + 1$ and $p^r \le n$, then the right-hand side is divisible by $p^r$ which forces some $\binom{n}{k}$ to be divisible by $p^r$. Such a prime $p$ exists for all large $n$ because the smallest $p$ not dividing $n + 1$ is at most $(1 + \text{o}(1))\log(n)$.

Comment: I think it's right but can you explain the last claim about the smallest p?

Comment: and the identity